# setting an array element with a sequence in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have features which is extracted using hog from images
but i am getting setting an array element with a sequence error
for my array list i can see size of feature_list is 272 however feature_list[0] size is 200 similary few elements have size 200 and few 400

How to solve this issue?

```
    features  = np.array(features_list, 'float64')

    # split the labled dataset into training / test sets
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, 
    features_label)

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    --
     ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
     last)
      <ipython-input-243-711263649759> in <module>
        1 # store features array into a numpy array
        ----> 2 features  = np.array(features_list, 'float64')
        3 #features_label_array=np.array(features_label,'float64')
        4 # split the labled dataset into training / test sets
       5 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, 
      features_label)

       ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: len(feature_list) is 272, len(feature_list[0]) is 200, len(feature_list[1]) is 400 do i need to pad elements in list? and if yes how?

Comment: Please post your code as *text*, not image, and don't use the comments for additional info (update your post instead) - https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @desertnaut provided code in post

Comment: Code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), adds unnecessary clutter, and should not be included here (edited out).